# Is it possible to call a python function with parameter from template? [Django]

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I read somewhere that it is not possible to call a python function in your template using django because django is one-way and that would raise security issues. I've been currently trying to use ajax/jquery to call a python function in my views.py during an onclick event.

Comment: In case anyone wondering, my project structure (parent_folder --> sub_folder, templates) where sub_folder contains views.py and templates contains myfile.html

Comment: Do you really have `$.getJSON('/mymethod', ...)`? If you called `$.getJSON('mymethod', ...)` (*without* the leading slash) from the URL `/myfile/`, then the relative URL `mymethod` would be turned to `/myfile/mymethod/`.

Comment: @Alasdair That doesn't change affected failed GET request. It would just fail at Not Found: /myfile/mymethod

Comment: Have you tried returning a string like `return 'Hello World!'` from the `mymethod()` function? I think the reason was because the function doesn't respond with any rendered string or literal string back to the client request.

Comment: @techfun679 I don't understand your reply. The `GET /myfile/mymethod HTTP/1.1 404"` strongly suggests that your `getJSON` line is wrong. If you show your actual code, it's much easier to help you, I can't offer any other suggestions if you have made-up variable names.

Comment: @VietHTran No, that has no effect on the error.

Comment: @techfun679 what if you put views.py in the parent folder?

Comment: @Alasdair Yes I know the getJSON line is wrong but, I do not know why. What code do you want to see?

Comment: @glhr That would mess up my entire project. I would think that the app routing would take care of that approach anyway @app.route('/mymethod')

Comment: @techfun679 how are you viewing your HTML file? Are you just opening the file directly or it's being rendered as a template?

Comment: @glhr I am running standard django method thru manage.py server and viewing webpage via localhost

Comment: @glhr I think I could actually solve this problem by moving functionality over to the root django file (manage.py)

Comment: *What code do you want to see?* the actual code and error message, instead of made-up variable names.

Comment: @Alasdair Not Found: /background_process_test
[01/Apr/2019 14:25:21] "GET /mymethod HTTP/1.1" 404 3527

Comment: @Alasdair Im not running flask, im just running django server

Comment: If it’s Django code, then why have you imported Flask? You shouldn’t combine Flask and Django like that. If `mymethod` is a Django view then you should include it in your urlpatterns. I can’t help any more until you [edit] your question and show actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you try giving the *full URL, to your webserver's mymethod route, within your `ajax` call*? Additionally, try returning a dummy `JSON` response for your `/mymethod` route and see if that helps? Something along the lines of:

**views.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

...

@app.route('/mymethod', methods=["GET"])
def mymethod():
    return jsonify({"Message": "/mymethod GET request", })
```

**myfile.html:**

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js</script>
 <script>
    $("a").click(function(e) {
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/mymethod', function(data) {
               // handle successful request
               console.log(data); // log your result to the console
            });
            return false;
    });
    </script>
```

I am assuming you're running on port 8000.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I am using port 8000 and properly adjusted for the record

Comment: I think I could actually solve this problem by moving functionality over to the root django file (manage.py)

Comment: Ok I adjusted my answer, maybe try specifying the supported methods on the mymethod route. Although flask should support GET routes by default.

Comment: Again unfortunately this has no affect. GET routes are default as I have seen by my error status messages.

Comment: Yes I mentioned they were supported by default as well, could you post your project structure? I am thinking this could be an issue with the project setup